# How to enable and disable a mouse click event on WPF using button

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I try to implement the mouse click event that can plot the map by using ThinkGeo. This function just active when i start running the code. I want to apply a button on the map so that it can enabled and disable the mouse click event on the map. Can someone show a sample or example for it, i think it need bool type variable right?

```
 private void map_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Map1.MapUnit = GeographyUnit.Meter;
            LayerOverlay myOverlay = new LayerOverlay();
            Map1.Overlays.Add(myOverlay);

            myOverlay.TileCache = new FileBitmapTileCache(@"..\..\Cache\");

            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\DSI REFERENCE\Map Data\Raster");

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                GeoTiffRasterLayer tiffLayer = new GeoTiffRasterLayer(file);

                myOverlay.Layers.Add(tiffLayer);
            }
            myOverlay.Open();
            Map1.CurrentExtent = myOverlay.GetBoundingBox();

            InMemoryFeatureLayer inmemoryFeatureLayer = new InMemoryFeatureLayer();
            inmemoryFeatureLayer.ZoomLevelSet.ZoomLevel01.DefaultPointStyle = new PointStyle(new GeoImage(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\15floors\Icon\Point.png"));
            inmemoryFeatureLayer.ZoomLevelSet.ZoomLevel01.ApplyUntilZoomLevel = ApplyUntilZoomLevel.Level20;

            LayerOverlay markerOverlay = new LayerOverlay();
            markerOverlay.Layers.Add(inmemoryFeatureLayer);
            Map1.Overlays.Add("MarkerOverlay", markerOverlay);

            Map1.Refresh();
        }

        private void Map1_MapClick(object sender, MapClickWpfMapEventArgs e)
        {

            LayerOverlay markerOverlay = (LayerOverlay)Map1.Overlays["MarkerOverlay"];
            InMemoryFeatureLayer inmemoryFeatureLayer = markerOverlay.Layers[0] as InMemoryFeatureLayer;

            MultipolygonShape buffer = e.WorldLocation.Buffer(350, GeographyUnit.Meter, DistanceUnit.Kilometer);

            inmemoryFeatureLayer.InternalFeatures.Add(new Feature(e.WorldLocation));




            Map1.Refresh();
        }

        private void Plot_ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

                InMemoryFeatureLayer inMemoryLayer = (InMemoryFeatureLayer)Map1.FindFeatureLayer("InMemoryFeatureLayer");
                inMemoryLayer.Open();
                inMemoryLayer.EditTools.BeginTransaction();
                inMemoryLayer.EditTools.Delete("MarkerOverlay");
                inMemoryLayer.EditTools.CommitTransaction();
                inMemoryLayer.Close();


                Map1.Refresh(Map1.Overlays["InmemoryOverlay"]);

        }

    }
```

Comment: As simple as you can do, create a toggle button nd a button then, in your button click event chick if button is toggled then execute, Or create binding if toggle button is on then enable button else disable

Comment: you could add a boolean value and if statement in the event handler. pretty much same as @ShubhamSahu suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to create a button, if you don't want the map control to generate mouse click events then just turn off hit testing:

```
Map1.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

Comment: i try it, it seem the it will disable all mouse function on the map. I just want to disable mouse click event only. In addition, i need the button to enable and disable the mouse click event if i wanted .

Comment: Technically there are ways to do this by using behaviors etc, but they're all overkill for something that is very easy to do in code. What's stopping you from just having a boolean value that you toggle when the button is pressed and then checking it in your handler?